# iOS Disable Auto Exposure - CvVideoCamera

Tags: ios, opencv, camera

Is there a way to disable auto exposure when using the iOS camera? I'm currently accessing it using OpenCV's CvVideoCamera object.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have something like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) cvVideoCamera *videoCamera;
```

You can lock/unlock focus, exposure, balance... by simply:

```
[self.videoCamera lockBalance];
[self.videoCamera lockExposure];
[self.videoCamera lockFocus];
```

Comment: And how can you lock it at a specific value? For example set exposure time to 20ms?